# What does span element contents ::after mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Newbie question which I haven't found answered anywhere (apologies if this is duplicate).

What is the meaning/purpose of the following HTML:

```
<span>::after</span>
```

Although I can't provide more specific context, I've seen this a few times in my travels around the web and it seems the span contents aren't rendered out on the page as content.

Working with my own code (modifying an existing page template), I managed to generate the same result and don't understand why.

My code:

```
$('#unique a').append('<div class="icon-col"><span class="icon"></span></div><div class="value-col"><span></span></div>');
```

Resultant HTML:

```
<div id="#unique">
<a href="#">
  <div class="icon-col">
    <span class="icon">
      ::after
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="value-col">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</a>
</div>
```

I'm familiar with *::after* in the context of CSS and jQuery selectors, I don't understand how that would apply in this context.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this in the browser’s Inspector?

Comment: You are looking for CSS pseudo elements. Check [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements). It is **not** HTML.

Comment: @kosmos _“I'm familiar with ::after in the context of CSS and jQuery selectors”_.

Comment: Assuming you are seeing this in the inspector, this is how the browser shows you that ::before or ::after content exists for this particular element (for Chrome dev tools and FF at least).

Comment: Oh my eyes, I didn't read that. Thanks for clarifying mate.

Comment: Answers:  In the wild I've seen this in published page source HTML.  In my own code, I see it in the browser console view of the source after executing the JavaScript.

Thanks for quick responses!  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's doing that because your "icon" class is making use of the ::after selector. When you inspect the element you will see what it's doing.